# Is there anyway to use "classic" ComboBox look with QtQuick.Controls 2.x

Tags: qt, combobox, qml, qtquick2

I need to use `ComboBox` that looks like this (sorry for the quality of the image, I can't upload image from where I am):

[image: this]

I also need to use `ComboBox` from `QtQuick.Controls 2.x` because I encountered a bug : `ComboBox` from  `QtQuick.Controls 1.x` doesn't catch my keyboards inputs (`Keys.onPressed` never triggers).

My problem is that `ComboBox` from  `QtQuick.Controls 2.x` doesn't look like "classic" ComboBox.

Is there a easy way to have a `QtQuick.Controls 2.x ComboBox` that has **same look** than  `QtQuick.Controls 1.x ComboBox` ?

Comment: Please show us the code in which it does not work, because for me it catches them perfectly.

Comment: I cannot have my project now. But it is really a specific code. I use a `TreeView` inside each Item of a `ListView`. Then I redraws each line of the `TreeView`. I also redraw the third column of the `TreeView` depending of the value of the second column on the same line. This is in the third column that I draw my `ComboBox`. Without any code modification, it works with `QtQuick.Controls 2.x` but not with `QtQuick.Controls 1.x`

Comment: Yeah, the problem is, when the `ComboBox` is open, it loses `activeFocus` as this is forwarded to the `Menu`. There it is used to enable the navigation with the up and down keys.

Comment: So in this case, I have to use ´QtQuick.Controls 2.x' right ?

Comment: It is probably easier. If I find some time, I will look into the code of the controls.

Comment: I will have a look to try to find a solution